# Calculation of SolidAngle not recognizing region?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, vector-calculus

Basically I'm trying to calculate the solid angle of a square seen from the origin. I defined the region (in two different ways) and tried running the function but it does not give any output.

Why is this not working, and how can I make it work?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this doesn't seem currently supported. Consider e-mailing Support about this.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful